# Accessing a javascript file in play framework

Tags: angularjs, playframework

value at is not a member of controllers.ReverseAssets

not able to access javascript file using '@routes.Assets.at("assets/app.js") '

```
<script src='@routes.Assets.**at**("assets/angular.min.js")'></script>
```

Comment: Is this an error you get? Can you edit your question to share the relevant parts of your code if so?

Comment: `@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/app.js")`

Comment: yeah....while accessing a javascript file,using line

Comment: an error occures 
 

value at is not a member of controllers.ReverseAssets

Comment: no govind,its the same thing,,only folder name changes

Comment: Add the tag your question with valid play version it will help to guess what's wrong

Comment: i think you forgot about javascript folder. 
if you have your script placed in public/javascript/assets/my.js 
you should use: 
@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/assets/my.js")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Framework @routes.Assets.at Compilation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562642/play-framework-routes-assets-at-compilation-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just switched to Play 2.4 check your `routes` file for assets path it may be `versioned` instead `at` like:

```
<script src='@routes.Assets.versioned("assets/angular.min.js")'></script>
```

Take a look into [**assets documentation for Play 2.4**](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#Reverse-routing-and-fingerprinting-for-public-assets) for more details